# Implement ModernHttpClient in flurl

Tags: android, xamarin.android, flurl

I've been receiving this error when attempting to make calls to my REST service via a Xamarin.Android app. **SecureChannelFailure (The authentication or decryption has failed.)** If I were using just a plain HttpClient this would be fixed by simply injecting ModernHttpClients MessageHandler like so

```
Httpclient client = new HttpClient(new ModernHttpClient.NativeMessageHandler());
```

This has been tested and works. However I am using flurl so I went ahead an attempted to customize the HttpClientFactory by overriding the CreateMessageHandler method from the DefaultHttpClientFactory class as per this [thread](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/issues/24)

Here is the gist

```
var client = new FlurlClient();
client.Settings.HttpClientFactory = new ModernHttpClientFactory();
var result = await "http://api.com".WithClient(client).GetAsync();
```

And the custom factory which simply uses ModernHttpClients handler.

```
public class ModernHttpClientFactory : DefaultHttpClientFactory
    {
        public override HttpMessageHandler CreateMessageHandler()
        {
            return new ModernHttpClient.NativeMessageHandler();
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work as I am getting the same error I was before. Any ideas on how to get this into flurl properly?

Comment: Of course shortly after posting I've solved my own problem. What worked for me was instead of creating a new client and injecting it with the "WithClient" method I used the "ConfigureClient" method which accepts an action that takes in a FlurlHttpSettings object. I then use the is object like so s.HttpClientFactory = new ModernHttpClientFactory()

Comment: More than a little late to respond, sorry. I'm actually a little surprised what you did worked. [Given the definition of `ConfigureClient`](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/blob/master/src/Flurl.Http.Shared/ClientConfigExtensions.cs#L58-L61) I would have expected the exact same behavior. You didn't change the factory definition at all?

Comment: @ToddMenier no I didn't change the definition. I was surprised too. When I get some time I will change my code back to the original way and see if the problem arises again. This way we will be a able to see if there really is a difference or just a fluke.